# How long does IIS keep site logs by default?

Tags: iis

Recently, I've noticed that the retention appears to be pretty long for most IIS servers I've worked with.

What is the default retention/how do I check it?

Answer (score 1):

The log retention appears to be version specific, but at least for IIS 6.2+ it appears that the retention by default is ***indefinite***.

You can check the log default settings for the entire server by going to:

`inetmgr ->  SERVERNAME -> Logging`

Here you can set logging styles, but there doesn't appear to be an "archive/cleanup" option, so likely if you want to actually delete these logs on a regular basis, a task will need to be created